# How to get single specific values for keys in json structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, json

I am doing some exercise like:

```
var jsonres;
jsonres = JSON.stringify(jsonObjectArray);
alert(jsonvals); // getting the below json structure

jsonres = {
    "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
    "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
    "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
    "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
    "key05": [[25, 50], "Some testing values"]
}
```

But I need like:

```
jsonres = {
    "key01": 10,
    "key02": false,
    "key03": null,
    "key04": "tests",
    "key05": [25,50]
}
```

How can I get like above structure(means I need only single values, don't need the second values/multiple values for the respective keys) ? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `for-in` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonres = {
    "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
    "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
    "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
    "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
    "key05": [[25, 50], "Some testing values"]
}

for(var key in jsonres){
   if(jsonres.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      jsonres[key] = jsonres[key][0];
   }
}

console.log(jsonres)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xd4nwc0m/

Comment: Since he's defined the object and it (seemingly) is just a value object, I don't think you need to check whether the object has it's own property at this point.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: its a defined object for us, not sure how it would be in real time app... its always better to check... regardless of you know your objects or not....

Comment: Worth mentioning, but in this case it's worth noting that while checking whether an object has it's own property is in most cases a good idea, it's not required to do so right after defining an object as in the example here. 

If OP is expecting this data to be built dynamically, or come from another resource then it's worth checking with the hasOwnProperty method.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: If OP is expecting this data to be built dynamically, or come from another resource then it's worth checking with the hasOwnProperty method.... this is my point... people don't put their entire code here on how the data comes or how its built... they all need a solution...

Comment: I know. I just wanted to make it clear to OP that if their intention is to define their object before re-assigning their keys (I can't see why they would, however - fair point) - that they don't need that check. It's worth while to check in most cases though.

Comment: @Thalaivar, thanks for your solution, I have applied the above in my task, but I am getting: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string '---'.

Comment: @Dhana: We need to look at your code... are you using Object.defineProperty to define your properties ...

Comment: @Thalaivar, yeah it is working fine now, I have resolved it now. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for(var key in jsonres) {
    jsonres[key] = jsonres[key][0];
}
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lzb1dum3/

Comment: thanks for your solution, I have applied the above in my task, but I am getting: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string '---'.

Comment: yeah it is working fine now. I have resolved. Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 1):

Just one line of code for iterating the keys and assigning:

```js
var jsonres = {
    "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
    "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
    "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
    "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
    "key05": [[25, 50], "Some testing values"]
}

Object.keys(jsonres).forEach(function (k) { jsonres[k] = jsonres[k][0]; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(jsonres, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```js
var editer = angular.module('editer', []);
function myCtrl($scope) {
$scope.jsonres = {
  "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
  "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
  "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
  "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
  "key05": [[25, 50], "Some testing values"]
} 

angular.forEach($scope.jsonres, function(value,key){
      $scope.jsonres[key] = value[0];
  });

console.log($scope.jsonres);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  
  <pre >{{jsonres|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this and see that it generates what you want:

```js
var jsonres = {
  "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
  "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
  "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
  "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
  "key05": [[25, 50], "Some testing values"]
} 

for (var key in jsonres) {
  jsonres[key] = jsonres[key][0];
  alert(jsonres[key]);
}
```